# My LaTex seems like can not recognized this table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I have a question related with Latex. I have problem with referencing table on my paragraph. I used **\ref{table7}** but the results were **"Table ??"** [image]. But the weird thing is, the table right before this one are fine and can be recognized. Anyone know how to solve this? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please copy and paste your code; images are much harder to deal with.  Have you tried having your label immediately after your caption?

Comment: Did you compile twice?

Comment: Note unrelated to your issue it can be confusing to use labels such as `table17` as the actual number may be different better to use something like `\label{std-jitter}`  so when you look at the source and and see `\ref{std-jitter}` you know which table is being referenced.

Comment: replace `\begin{center}...\end{center}` by `\centering` the environment form will add unwanted space, ad hide the `\caption` from the `\label` command